# SQL select result of stored procedure into a comment

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am return a result set from a stored procedure (multiple columns). I am able to populate values for columns from functions (`getContactDisplayName`), e.g.:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT [dbo].getContactDisplayName([Form_Response_ID])) AS Submitted_By
FROM 
    foo_Table;
```

I would like to do the exact same thing with a stored procedure (`sp_GetFormAnswer`), e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT EXEC sp_GetFormAnswer @FieldName = 'Submission_Data') AS Answer
FROM 
    foo_Table;
```

Is this possible? If so, why not? What are my alternatives? I do have to use a stored procedure, as that stored procedure calls dynamic SQL (which uses `exec`, which functions cannot do).

Note - the code is tested, populating columns from functions works fine, as does the stored procedure, on its own. Just not inside the select.

EDIT: My actual, full, working, stored procedure (sorry, it's not on the test db):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.crds_sp_GetFormAnswer 
    @FieldName varchar(max), 
    @TableName varchar(max), 
    @PrimaryKeyColumnName varchar(max), 
    @DataRecordId int
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + @FieldName +
              ' FROM ' + @TableName + 
              ' WHERE ' + @PrimaryKeyColumnName + '  =  ' + STR(@DataRecordId) + ';';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
            N'@FieldName varchar(max), @TableName varchar(max), 
              @PrimaryKeyColumnName varchar(max), @DataRecordId int', 
            @FieldName = @FieldName, @TableName = @TableName, 
            @PrimaryKeyColumnName = @PrimaryKeyColumnName, @DataRecordId = @DataRecordId;
GO

--test
EXEC crds_sp_GetFormAnswer @FieldName = 'Submission_Data', 
                           @TableName = 'cr_Submissions', 
                           @PrimaryKeyColumnName = 'Submission_ID', 
                           @DataRecordId = 15;
```

In short, my end goal is to use dynamic SQL to populate a field. I have to use dynamic SQL because I am selecting from any number of tables. Business req was that use creates report to write to any table in the db if they have permissions (which is a separate topic).

[image]

**NOTE:** I want to pass different data from each row into the stored procedure and have a different output for each row.

Comment: You would have to create a temp table or a variable from the stored procedure. But you are going to need to share some code here to get anything resembling a real answer.

Comment: @SeanLange Done.

Comment: Your dynamic sql is not going to work. You can't parameterize objects in dynamic sql. Maybe this is a greatly simplified version for your question?

Comment: @SeanLange I just verified that it works. See screenshot. Somehow my comment sounds snappy even to me - I don't mean it that way, appreciate your help.

Comment: I certainly don't read it that way...and mine is not intended to sound that way either. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a temp table(As some of the comments say), change the returned result set.

```
EXEC usp_Get_TwoColumnsData
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
       NewReturnedColumnName1 VARCHAR(1337) NOT NULL,
       NewReturnedColumnName2 VARCHAR(1337) NOT NULL
    )
)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I am trying to run this for each individual row and pass params to the SP for each row, will this solution work?

Comment: Well, if your stored procedure works and gives an output, then you can alter what it returns by altering the result set.

Comment: @VSO Note: if Sean's attempt doesn't work, then this will aslo not work, as it is 2 sides of the same coin.

Comment: ty for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I will just assume that your dynamic sql posted is valid (see my comment on the OP). If you are on a version earlier than 2012 you can do this using a table variable or temp table. Here is how you can do this using a table variable.

```
declare @Result table
(
    Result varchar(max) --or whatever datatype makes sense here
)

insert @Result
EXEC crds_sp_GetFormAnswer @FieldName = 'Submission_Data', @TableName = 'cr_Submissions', 
                           @PrimaryKeyColumnName = 'Submission_ID', @DataRecordId = 15;
```

Comment: Sean, I am on 2012, will this not work for me or worth a try?

Comment: It will still work. Was somewhat referring to the other answer using a totally different approach that was not available until 2012.

Comment: Sean, my bad, I should have clarified, but the string constants/ints I have filled in are unique to each row in my select statement. I am not quite sure that this will work.

Comment: Ouch....then you are pretty much stuck. You can't call a procedure for each row in a select statement like it seems you need to do. The obvious next question is why is the design such that you have to use dynamic sql here? Using different tables to store essentially the same data is a big red flag that something is amiss.